# git: avoiding merge conflicts in git-notes

Tags: git

is there a best approach for resolving merge conflicts in notes branch(git-notes) of git. The usual practice of doing a

```
git pull --rebase origin refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/commits
```

does not work. The approach which i tried was

```
git checkout refs/notes/commits
git fetch origin refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/origin/commits 
git merge FETCH_HEAD 
git update-ref refs/notes/commits
```

but it creates merge conflicts and disrupts the history. Please help.
Immediate help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yet, the git merge approach seems the recommended approach... See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16269354/6309 and the script https://github.com/aspiers/git-config/blob/master/bin/git-rnotes

Comment: the command

    git notes merge -v origin/commits is not working

Comment: What is the error message? Or is it only because it generates conflicts?

Comment: "git notes merge -v origin/commits" does not seem to merge the non-conflicted files. For example, if there is a conflict in file A, then file A gets merged, but file B does not get merged.. :( pain of a process..

Comment: Interesting, that is not what http://stackoverflow.com/a/16269354/6309 is saying: "If there are conflicts, it will now tell you to edit `.git/NOTES_MERGE_WORKTREE` and then commit the result via `git notes merge --commit`"

Comment: thanks, was probably a little impatient, but was able to sort it out.. :)

Comment: Great. I have added an answer to summarize this conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, if there is a conflict in file `A`, then file A gets merged, but file `B` does not get merged

As mentioned in "[Merging git notes when there are merge conflicts in them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16269354/6309)"

```
git fetch origin refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/origin/commits
git notes merge -v origin/commits
```

> If there are conflicts, it will now tell you to edit `.git/NOTES_MERGE_WORKTREE` and then commit the result via `git notes merge --commit`, or abort the merge with `git notes merge --abort`.

So `B` should get merged after the `git notes merge --commit`.

Note: Git 2.6 (Q3/Q4 2015) will add [`git notes merge` strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32327618/6309).